# Elasticsearch - Checking the object type in query

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I have upgraded my elasticsearch from v1.9 to v5 and I have noticed that a lot of things have changed.

If I were to take an example from v1.9: The below code checks whether the object type matches `ObjectAdo` and it filters the items within `ObjectAdo` that have the `IsDeleted` field as `false`.

```
private Func<FilterDescriptor<dynamic>, FilterContainer> Filter()
        {
            return b => b.Bool(x => x.Must(m => m.Type(typeof(ObjectAdo)), n => n.Term("IsDeleted", false)));
        }
```

Now, after upgrading from v1.9 to v5, I noticed that `FilterDescriptor` got changed to `QueryContainerDescriptor` and `FilterContainer` is now `QueryContainer`. Now I am unable to perform the same operation as before because `.Type(typeof(ObjectAdo)` is no longer available.

So I am wondering if there is an alternative solution to check the object type.